# how to add escape sequence for BELL (U+0007)() control character in java

Tags: java, unicode-string, mongo-java-driver, control-characters

I am facing the parsing issue with some control characters. I have a string which contains a UNICODE control character. We are using a json parser from "mongodb"(mongo-java-driver) library to parse the given string. It is throwing JSONParserException.

Code Snippet:

```
String ctrlStr = "{\"location\": \"\"}";
try {
JSONParse.parse(ctrlStr)
} catch(Exception e) {
 log.error(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

Note: "bell" symbol is not displayed in the code snippet.

Could any body let me know how to add escape sequence for "" (bell) symbol.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu Do you know Reddappa Reddy? You have changed the question a lot, making assumptions that were not obvious from the previous question.

Comment: Hello @MalteHartwig,    The above modification is correct.

Answer (score 1):

JSON strings may not contain control characters ([reference](http://www.json.org/)).

Instead you can write the ASCII text `\u0007`. Notice that this is in java:

```
"\\u0007"
```

(escaped) as otherwise you again would have the BEL control character.

Replacing:

```
s = s.replace("\u0007", "\\u0007");
```